# Uk postcode validation Warning message

Tags: php, regex, validation, codeigniter

I have the following code to validate uk postcodes I am using this as validation rule in codeigniter but I am getting the following warning message:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 426
>
> Filename: models/user_profile.php
>
> Line Number: 126

It always returns false as well no matter which postcode is entered can anybody spot what is wrong?

```
//Check and validate uk postcode
function _valid_postcode($field) {
    $regex = '!^([A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Ya-hk-y][0-9]|[A-HK-Ya-hk-y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRV-Yabehmnprv-y]))|[0-9][A-HJKS-UWa-hjks-uw])\{0,1}[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}|([Gg][Ii][Rr]\0[Aa][Aa])|([Ss][Aa][Nn]\{0,1}[Tt][Aa]1)|([Bb][Ff][Pp][Oo]\{0,1}([Cc]\/[Oo]\)?[0-9]{1,4})|(([Aa][Ss][Cc][Nn]|[Bb][Bb][Nn][Dd]|[BFSbfs][Ii][Qq][Qq]|[Pp][Cc][Rr][Nn]|[Ss][Tt][Hh][Ll]|[Tt][Dd][Cc][Uu]|[Tt][Kk][Cc][Aa])\{0,1}1[Zz][Zz]))$!';

    $result = preg_match($regex, $field);

    if($result > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->error_message($field, 'Please enter a valid postcode');
        //return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify your regex by making it case-insensitive.

Comment: Doesn't seem to like SW1A 1AA, which is a valid UK postcode

Answer (score 0):

> missing )

Your (first) opening `(` doesn't have a closing `)`. I suggest using a text editor (such as [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)) that will help you match your parentheses.

I can't tell from that massive regular expression *where* the closing `)` should go.

Perhaps try one of these: http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=260

For example:

```
function is_valid_postcode($postcode) {
    $validation_expression = '/^(((([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][0-9A-HJKS-UW]?)|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][0-9ABEHMNPRV-Y]?))\s{0,2}[0-9]([ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))|(GIR\s{0,2}0AA))$/i';

    return preg_match($validation_expression, $postcode);
}
```

...returns the expected results on the samples I tried (including 'SW1A 1AA') and adding the `i` to the end deals nicely with lowercase postcode entries.

---

Following comments.

This does not deal with leading or trailing whitespace. You could easily add a call to [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) if this presents an issue for you. I wouldn't add this to the regular expression, as it's already very long.

And according to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-match.php)...

> `preg_match()` returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because `preg_match()` will stop searching after the first match. `preg_match()` returns `FALSE` [`0`] if an error occurred.

Comment: ok updated my function with your regex but its still always returning the error message as above

Comment: I think the problem lies in if($result > 0) im not sure what preg_match is supposed to return currently it seems to be causing it to return false all the time

Comment: If you are getting the same error message, you still have the same problem.

Comment: @user794846: If you're not sure what a function is supposed to return, you should read the documentation (I've linked to this in my answer now)! Perhaps you could update your question with some sample data that fails your test.